# error TS2322: Type '"openDialog('https://someurl.sharepoint.com/...' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, onclick, render

I am trying to call Javascript function from react rendor method, just like as below

```html
        <button onClick="openDialog('https://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/Lists/EventsCalendar/calendar.aspx')">
Office Holidays
      </button>
```

It gives me an error

[15:09:24] Error - typescript - src\webparts\HomeEvents\components\HomeEvents.tsx(69,13): error TS2322: Type '"openDialog('https://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/Lists/EventsCal...' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler>'.

Comment: You are calling a function and pass the value of that function to ```onClick```. You need to pass a function to ```onClick``` not a value from a function

Comment: Yes I know that but if i called that function directly then it needs function definition which is not defined in the component instead definition besides into the js file

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the function to `onClick` in wrong way. You need to change your `onClick` function as below

```
 <button onClick={() => openDialog('https://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/Lists/EventsCalendar/calendar.aspx')}>
Office Holidays
      </button>
```

Comment: This will gives me an error Property 'openDialog' does not exist on type 'Events'

Comment: In that case, you need to import openDialog function into your component file

Comment: how can I do that? as the function written inside the JS file

Comment: in the file has ```function openDialog``` function, change your function to ```export function openDialog```. Then in your component file ```import { openDialog } from 'path-to-open-dialog-file';```

Comment: while importing js function Error - typescript - src\webparts\HomeEvents\components\HomeEvents.tsx(7,27): error TS6143: Module '../../../js/custom' was resolved to 'D:/SPFx/src/js/custom.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.

Comment: Please add ```"allowJS": true``` to your ```"compilerOptions"``` in your ```tsconfig.json``` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196859/discussion-between-mr-roshan-and-tien-duong).